# ¿Como puedo sumar los datos y mostrarlos en pantalla?

Tags: mongodb

Como se puede apreciar en la siguiente imagen, hay una serie de articulos de los cuales necesito saber **¿Qué cantidad de cuadernos se encuentran en el inventario?** e imprimir el resultado.

**¿Qué comando debo usar?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Antes usaba el codigo

```
db.inventario.count(
{articulo:"Cuaderno"}
)
```

Pero me di cuenta de que solo me mostraba la cantidad de articulos con el nombre cuaderno y es aqui cuando no tengo idea de como especificarle la suma de tales valores que necesito.

Comment: ¿Y tu código? Una imagen no nos demuestra un problema

Answer (score 0):

Aquí debes emplear [mongodb aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html)

Puedes realizar la operación de varias maneras:

A) Si solamente necesitas los articulos tipo cuaderno, debes realizar una serie de pasos:

1- Filtrado del campo "artículo" para que sea "cuaderno"

2- Agrupar por ese campo para realizar el sumatorio

```
db.inventario.aggregate([
{
    "$match": {
        "articulo": "cuaderno"
    }
},
{
    "$grup": {
        "_id": "$articulo",
        "stock": {"$sum": "$cantidad"}
    }
}
])
```

B) Si quieres la agrupación de cada artículo con su sumatorio solamente tienes que eliminar el primer paso y agrupar:

```
db.inventario.aggregate([
{
    "$grup": {
        "_id": "$articulo",
        "stock": {"$sum": "$cantidad"}
    }
}
])
```

Aquí tienes el ejemplo: https://play.db-ai.co/m/XoHtJn7kZQABtA1f